# How to use Lambda functions in SciPy Orthogonal Distance Regression (ODR)?

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, parameter-passing, index-error

I am trying to fit different curves to the same data using SciPy's ODR. To make this easier, I have defined each candidate function as a Lambda function. This Lambda function then gets passed on to ODR through a function of my own, called `odr_fit()`:

```
    if trend_name == 'linear':
        eps = odr_fit(f=lambda x, p: p[0]*x+p[1], xdata=x, ydata=y)
    elif trend_name == 'quadratic':
        eps = odr_fit(f=lambda x, p: p[0]*x**2+p[1]*x+p[2], xdata=x, ydata=y)
    # and so on....
```

The `odr_fit()` function is defined as follows:

```
def odr_fit(f, xdata, ydata):
    """
    Function to calculate orthogonal residuals given data and a function to fit
    :param f: function in the format f(x, p), where p is a list of parameters
    :param xdata: Pandas Series with independent variable
    :param ydata: Pandas Series of same length with dependent variable
    :return: eps: estimated orthogonal errors, same length as xdata and ydata
    """
    f = np.vectorize(f, excluded=['p'])
    model = Model(f)
    data = RealData(xdata, ydata)
    odr = ODR(data, model, beta0=[10]*3) # beta0 is an initial estimate. Should be the same length as p ideally as well
    odr_result = odr.run()
    return odr_result.eps
```

**My problem**: somewhere in this code, `p` (the parameters, the second argument of my Lambda function) is expected to be a scalar. I want it to be seen as a list or tuple.

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

ODR also expects a list/tuple (see documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html)). Of course, I could just define each function separately, but this would be cumbersome and harder to expand. Is there a way of making ODR work using Lambda functions? Perhaps something that can force `p` to be a vector of a certain length.

Hope someone knows a solution to this!

Thanks,

Alex

EDIT: Here is the error in full:

```
ERROR - <class 'IndexError'>: invalid index to scalar variable.
<traceback object at 0x000001F4669271C8>
ERROR - <class 'IndexError'>: invalid index to scalar variable.
<traceback object at 0x000001F4669271C8>
ERROR - <class 'IndexError'>: invalid index to scalar variable.
<traceback object at 0x000001F4669271C8>
ERROR - <class 'IndexError'>: invalid index to scalar variable.
<traceback object at 0x000001F4669271C8>
ERROR - <class 'IndexError'>: invalid index to scalar variable.
<traceback object at 0x000001F4669271C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\features.py", line 296, in add_features
    data = _add_trend_features(data, col_trends={'x':'TemperatureOutsideAvgNight', 'y':'TemperatureInsideAvgNight'})
  File "C:\Users\...\trend_features.py", line 109, in _add_trend_features
    return_orth_dist=True)
  File "C:\Users\...\trend_features.py", line 88, in _add_trend_features
    eps = odr_fit(f=lambda x, p: p[0]*x+p[1], xdata=x, ydata=y)
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\phil_anomaly_detection\phil_anomaly_detection\trend_features.py", line 23, in odr_fit
    odr = ODR(data, model, beta0=[10]*3)
  File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\odr\odrpack.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._check()
  File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\odr\odrpack.py", line 831, in _check
    res = self.model.fcn(*arglist)
  File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2161, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2121, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
  File "C:\Users\...\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2086, in func
    return self.pyfunc(*the_args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\trend_features.py", line 88, in <lambda>
    eps = odr_fit(f=lambda x, p: p[0]*x+p[1], xdata=x, ydata=y)
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I recommend tracing the type of `p` in each step, may it be using the debugger or the poor-man's-debugger (printing the type ;) ).

Comment: Thanks Scotty. `p` isn't a variable as such, just a sort of handle for the parameters of the function to be fit. Not sure how to describe it. Maybe posting the full error will make things clearer.

Comment: Yep, but you still need to check where it is converted to a scalar. Looking at the trace, it seems to happen while defining the lambda fun.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks. Any way to force p to be a certain length? From other programming languages it would be something like:

`odr_fit(f=lambda x, p as tuple(length=3): p[1] + p[0]*x, xdata=x, ydata=y)`

Comment: `length=3` of course, but you get the idea